# ¿Por qué me sale "No hay ninguna cola de revisión disponible para ti" en la

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión

Desde hace unos días al ver las colas de revisión tanto en el sitio principal com en Meta me dice que:

> No hay ninguna cola de revisión disponible para ti

¿Alguien sabe a qué es debido?

Comment: Te pasa en meta o en SOes?

Comment: Puedes acceder al chat en algun momento?

Comment: En SOes y tb en Meta. Si, puedo acceder al chat, no sabia ni que existía, la verdad

Comment: Yo pienso que has tenido muchas fallas y te han suspendido temporalmente de la revisión.

Comment: relacionado: [“There are no review queues available to you” - Hey?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-hey)

Comment: Te recomiendo ver el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review

Answer (score 3):

Como indica eyllanesc en un comentario, se debe a la suspensión temporal de las colas de revisión.

La semana pasada se te bloqueó de las mismas.

El sistema permite dejar un mensaje de explicación que se ve que no te ha llegado o con el que no te has topado.

Te pedimos disculpas por parte del equipo de moderación por no haber mandado un mensaje privado además del mensaje de la suspensión de colas.

Si lo deseas, podemos discutir en privado los motivos de la suspensión temporal.

Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b una consulta: debido a que el sistema de penalización en las colas de revisión recien lleva pocos meses implementado ¿existe alguna estadística al respecto?

Comment: @eyllanesc creo que te refieres a las auditorías y si, se nos permite ver los aciertos y fallos de las mismas

Comment: @lois6b seria genial que en algun momento se publique los resultados para que en un futuro podamos sacar conclusiones.

Comment: @eyllanesc supongo que podamos publicar estadísticas generales . Pero a nivel general de qué serviría ? Cada usuario sabe si lo hace bien o mal.